# How to check if a variable is empty within Wordpress widget function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress widget to output some reusable content.  I have an instance variable set as follows:

```
$pagelink = empty($instance['page-link']) ? '' : $instance['page-link'];
```

This variable links to the Website Link field here:

[image]

I need to check whether this field, and therefore the `$pagelink` variable, is empty.  If it is, I don't output the website link on the page.

Here is the full function:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
    $year = empty($instance['year']) ? '' : $instance['year'];
    $description = empty($instance['description']) ? '' : $instance['description'];
    $tag = empty($instance['tag']) ? '' : $instance['tag'];
    $link = empty($instance['link']) ? '' : $instance['link'];
    $pagelink = empty($instance['page-link']) ? '' : $instance['page-link'];
    echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; ?>

    <small><?php echo $year ?></small>
    <p><?php echo $description ?></p>
    <small><?php echo $tag ?></small>
    <a href="<?php echo $link ?>">Source code</a>
    <?php empty($pagelink) ? '' : '<a href="<?php echo $pagelink ?>">Website</a>' ?>

    <?php echo $args['after_widget'];

  }
```

Using this code the Website link doesn't output whether the field is empty or not.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Think I figured it out, if I code as follows:

`<?php echo $pagelink === '' ? '' : '<a href="<?php echo $pagelink ?>">Website</a>' ?>`

That seems to work.

Just not sure if this is necessarily the correct way to do this...but works for now!